# Blank Screen on ListActivity Populated from mySQL

Tags: android, mysql, arrays, listview, listactivity

This is my first attempt at creating a ListActivity populated from a remote mySQL database. I had this working fine while getting data from the local SQLite database.  I needed to revise my class to get the data from a remote database instead so I attempted to tweak my class to do this by following tutorials and the docs. Because of the complexity of my view and use of 'getExtras', I am unable to figure this out.

My question is: Now with the revision, I get a blank list returned with no errors in LogCat; so what can you see is at fault with my class?  Recommendations?

```
public class QueryDisplayList extends ListActivity {

    private static final String PHP_KEY = "PHP_KEY";
    private static final String QUERY_ORDER = "QUERY_ORDER";

    JSONArray jArray;
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;

    // private Object tvLabel = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view2);

        /**
         * Get the query string from last activity and pass it to this
         * activity-----------------------------------------------------
         */
        // String p = null;
        // if (extras != null) {
        // p = extras.getString(PHP_KEY);
        // }
        loadQuery();
    }

    void loadQuery() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                String qO = getIntent().getStringExtra("QUERY_ORDER");
                String php = getIntent().getStringExtra("PHP_KEY");

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // http post
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://10.0.2.2/App/php/" + php + qO + ".php");

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Fetched " + php + qO + ".php");

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                }

                // convert response to string
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

            }
        }).start();

        setListAdapter(new QueryAdapter(this, result));
    }

    /**
     * The Query Adaptor --------------------------------------------
     */

    private class QueryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private Activity context;

        public QueryAdapter(Activity context, String result) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_view2);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);

            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    final String tvLabel = json_data.getString("label");
                    TextView labelTxt = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.label);
                    if (labelTxt != null) {
                        labelTxt.setText("(" + tvLabel + ")");
                    }

                    final String tvTitle = json_data.getString("title");
                    TextView titleTxt = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
                    if (titleTxt != null) {
                        titleTxt.setText(tvTitle);
                    }

                    String tvDescription = json_data.getString("description");
                    TextView descriptionTxt = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.caption);
                    if (descriptionTxt != null) {
                        descriptionTxt.setText(tvDescription);
                    }

                    String tvDate = json_data.getString("date");
                    TextView dateTxt = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.dateAdded);
                    if (dateTxt != null) {
                        dateTxt.setText(tvDate);
                    }

                    String tvGoto = json_data.getString("gotoURL");
                    TextView gotoTxt = (TextView) convertView
                            .findViewById(R.id.dummy);
                    if (gotoTxt != null) {
                        gotoTxt.setText(tvGoto);
                    }

                    gotoTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    convertView.setTag(gotoTxt);

                    final String ni = json_data.getString("intent");

                    final ListView lv = getListView();
                    lv.setEnabled(true);
                    lv.setClickable(true);

                    /**
                     * Click Listeners --------------------------------
                     */
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {

                            // -- Set the domain name in the strings.xml file
                            // once
                            // the
                            // DNS is established for the website.
                            String mDomain = getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.domain);

                            String url = "";
                            url = mDomain + (String) v.getTag();

                            String intent = ni;
                            Class<?> nIntent = null;
                            try {
                                nIntent = Class
                                        .forName("com.andaerosystems.andaero.utili."
                                                + intent);
                            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Intent i = new Intent(QueryDisplayList.this,
                                    nIntent);
                            i.putExtra("PHP_KEY", tvLabel);
                            i.putExtra("KEY_URL", url);
                            i.putExtra("KEY_SUBTITLE", tvTitle);
                            i.putExtra("KEY_LABEL", tvLabel);
                            i.putExtra("KEY_INTENT", intent);
                            i.putExtra("QUERY_ORDER", "ASC");
                            i.putExtra("KEY_YPOS", "0.0");
                            QueryDisplayList.this.startActivity(i);

                            Log.e("tag", url);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No label Found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took quick look at your code. Try this.

```
void loadQuery() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                String qO = getIntent().getStringExtra("QUERY_ORDER");
                String php = getIntent().getStringExtra("PHP_KEY");

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // http post
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://10.0.2.2/App/php/" + php + qO + ".php");

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Fetched " + php + qO + ".php");

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                }

                // convert response to string
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                   YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                YourActivity.this.setListAdapter(new QueryAdapter(this, result));
            }});

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }


            }
        }).start();


    }
```

Comment: Thnx!  That was a step forward but now I am getting FATAL EXCEPTION: main
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.andaerosystems.andaero.utili.QueryDisplayList$1$1 cannot be cast to android.content.Context
at com.andaerosystems.andaero.utili.QueryDisplayList$QueryAdapter`  Not sure what to do from here..? Any more help? Thnx! @Nikola Despotoski

Comment: You are making some faulty casting...check the line at which exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug it step by step and checked out the resulting values of the variables?

An example: With parsing a json file a typo or the an error from getString() stops the proces.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't pass the new result you receive from HttpPost to your adapter (since the adapter is created before you get the response).

Also, `getView` isn't meant to be used like this. What it does is create a single item in the list. What you are doing is creating all the items. What you should do is parse the data and add the list with the parsed data to the adapter.

Take a look a this for an example of this: http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications.